# How do I make a script to select certain layers according to an xml file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hello I am Joel Machado and I am a simple technician and computer programmer. At one week while working one of my co-workers working with illustrator asked me to develop a sricpt or a macro to select multiple layers according to an xml file. This is the first time I work with script or macros in ilustrator if someone can help me I'm grateful. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - please take a peek at [tour] to get a sense of our community; please also look at [ask] and [answer] a question to understand what make a good question here and how to frame it, and what to expect from answers and other replies. We do have a fair few folks who are skilled at scripting here, but it seems to me there's a fair chance this question may get migrated to https://superuser.com/users/886501/ as it's pretty close to the edge of our scope here.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, open extend script toolkit. Its adobes own IDE for the javascript API (called extendscript; *.jsx). Not a stellar editor but attaches a debugger by default, which is useful.

You need to start your scripts with

```
#target illustrator
```

So the engine knows to target illustrator. Then implement a javascript file just as you would normally. Catch is that you need to use adobes API for this. The etendscipt toolkit has a full reference but you can find the reference for illustrator on [Illustrator Scripting page](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html).

In addition to this you probably need to refer to the [JSX tools guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj-h634lPPgAhXSpYsKHTWGDMIQFjABegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.adobe.com%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Facom%2Fen%2Fdevnet%2FImages%2FJavaScript-Tools-Guide-CC.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0A49E6KNUibkACSk27CSQE) as it tells you about the file and xml API's that extendscript comes with. Remember this is not a browser implementation of javascript so you cant extpect normal javascipt browser API's to work.